# How to optimize iterating over a huge dataframe with non-unique rows

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, dplyr, data.table

I understand that if R is not updating a variable in place within the confines of a for loop then I've just made some horrendously slow and expensive code. Unfortunately, with a set of very tight deadlines and a strong background in C++/Java it's my go-to behaviour until I can get my R hat on.

I have a function I need to improve. It takes a dataframe (as below) returns the unique *patid* values and uses those to retrieve subsets of that dataframe for date modifications. A trimmed example below (note, I just pulled this out of a completed run, so the date has already been modified). The last R run I performed was over a dataframe of 27 million row and took about four/five hours. The size of the dataframe will be a lot bigger.

```
patid eventdate
1     12/03/1998   
1     12/03/1998   
2     04/03/2007   
3     15/11/1980   
3     15/11/1980   
3     01/02/1981
```

A trimmed example of the function:

```
rearrangeDates <- function(dataFrame) {
   #return a list of the unique patient ids
   uniquePatids <- getUniquePatidList(dataFrame) #this is only called once and is very fast

    out=NULL
    for(i in 1:length(uniquePatids)) { # iterate over the list 
        idf <- subset(dataFrame, dataFrame$patid=uniquePatids[[i]])
        idf$eventdate <- as.POSIXct(idf$eventdate,format="%d/%m/%Y")
        idf <- idf[order(idf$eventdate,decreasing=FALSE),]
        out = rbind(out,idf)
    }
    return(out)
}
```

Can anyone suggest improvements?

Comment: Are you essentially just trying to convert the dates to `POSIX.ct` and then order by patid and ascending date?

Comment: try `library(dplyr);
df %>%
  mutate(eventdate = as.Date(eventdate, format="%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  arrange(patid, eventdate)`

Comment: In reply to @neilfws yes! However, what I need to keep in mind is that a patid entry is not unique i.e., the patient "Bob" who is #1 has been twice, whilst "James" (#3) has been three times. Hence why I then subset by a list of the patids and then recombine at the end.

Comment: Thanks @Prem I'll try what you've got there.

Comment: @Prem wow! That's taken something which took hours and reduced it to seconds! Thanks.

Comment: Do you keep reading in input dates as strings, and converting them to `as.Date()`, inside every loop iteration?! Just do `dataFrame$eventdate <- as.POSIXct(dataFrame$eventdate,format="%d/%m/%Y")` once, outside the loop.

Comment: Also you can use a `data.table` and key on `eventdate`. That throws out another line of loop code: `idf <- idf[order(idf$eventdate,decreasing=FALSE),]`

Comment: And the iterative append `out = rbind(out,idf)` is a notorious antipattern. You already know the output df will have a length of `length(uniquePatids)`, you can predeclare it outside the loop. Inside the loop, don't do append, just directly assign to rows of outputDf.

Comment: @smci thanks! Your comment concerning the `rbind` is a great solution to some other big slowdowns in my code!

Comment: Did you intend to have duplicates in your input `(1,12/03/1998)` and `(3,15/11/1980)`, and is it ok to only write out one of each? And you also want `(3, 01/02/1981)` written out; so two output rows for patid==3? Because if you keep duplicates, your outputDf will have length > `length(uniquePatids)`, and we may have to append, not assign directly. It would help if patid was a unique key in the output df.

Comment: PS you didn't define `getUniquePatidList(dataFrame)`, but both `dplyr`/ `data.table` do fast `unique(df$patid)`. But **you should *never* have to manually generate and subset by vectors of unique ids**, both `dplyr`/ `data.table` do fast group-by operations, allow them handle the unique/distinct rows. A code smell if you ever find yourself manually handling vectors of unique ids,  you don't need to... See e.g. [`dplyr::distinct()`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct.html)

Comment: @Prem you should put that as an answer.

Comment: @HongOoi done :)

Comment: @Prem yep, the duplicates are intended i.e., patid is a medical patient and this is their history, one visit per row. . As you said, I can't use the length of the list to define, however, your answer (below) worked and you've pointed me to dplyr, which looks to be very useful.

Comment: My answer works too, once you clarified you want duplicates left in. `data.table` should be faster on this. Please confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to sort your data on `patid` & `eventdate` this should work.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(eventdate = as.Date(eventdate, format="%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  arrange(patid, eventdate)
```

**Output is:**

```
  patid  eventdate
1     1 1998-03-12
2     1 1998-03-12
3     2 2007-03-04
4     3 1980-11-15
5     3 1980-11-15
6     3 1981-02-01
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(patid = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), eventdate = c("12/03/1998", 
"12/03/1998", "04/03/2007", "15/11/1980", "15/11/1980", "01/02/1981"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ideally suited to `data.table`: your data has a well-defined key that you group-by `(patid,eventdate)`, you know the size of the output df will be <= size of input df, so it's safe to do do in-place assignments (waaay faster) instead of appends, you don't need the output iterative-append, and data.table has a nice fast `unique` function. So please try out the (loop-free!) code below and let us know how it compares both to your original, and to the `dplyr` approach:

```
require(data.table)
dt = data.table(patid=c(1,1,2,3,3,3), eventdate=c('12/03/1998','12/03/1998',
         '04/03/2007', '15/11/1980', '15/11/1980','01/02/1981'))  
dt[, eventdate := as.POSIXct(eventdate,format="%d/%m/%Y") ]

# If you set a key, the `by` operation will be super-fast
setkeyv(dt, c('patid','eventdate'))

odt <- dt[, by=.(patid,eventdate)]

   patid  eventdate
1:     1 1998-03-12
2:     1 1998-03-12
3:     2 2007-03-04
4:     3 1980-11-15
5:     3 1980-11-15
6:     3 1981-02-01
```

(One last thing: don't be afraid of POSIXct/lt, convert to them early, they're more efficient than strings, they support comparison operators hence the column can be used as key, sorted on, compared.)

(And for the fastest `dplyr` implementation, use [`dplyr::distinct()`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct.html))